# SQL Borrando Registros - Delete y Where no borran cuando existe la letra "ñ" en el campo de comparación

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo dos bases de datos access, de las cuales quiero borrar registros de una tabla a partir de una condición en la cláusula where. **La consulta funciona bien, excepto en el caso de registros que contienen "ñ" dentro de los campos en base a los cuales estoy haciendo la comparación. La consulta es la siguiente**

```
DELETE [TABLA_Historico].*  FROM [RutaBase\Base1.mdb].[TABLA] 
  AS [TABLA_Historico],[RutaBase\Base2.mdb].RESULTADO_HISTORICO 
  WHERE ((RESULTADO_HISTORICO.Catalogo = [TABLA_Historico].Catalogo) 
  AND (RESULTADO_HISTORICO.Articulo = [TABLA_Historico].Articulo))
```

Como resultado esta consulta borra todos los registros de TABLA de la Base1 en los cuales la combinación de campos "Catalogo" y "Articulo" existe en la tabla RESULTADO_HISTORICO de la Base2. **Repito la consulta funciona, el problema es que no borra los registros cuando los campos "Catalogo" o "Articulo" contienen una "ñ"**

Comment: ¿en ambas tablas tienes valores con `ñ`? , ¿qué otro criterio tienes para eliminar los registros? la verdad no comprendo cómo la `ñ` influye en esto.

Comment: ¿Has declarado las agrupaciones (`collate`)?, a veces hay caracteres que la tabla no reconoce por el collate. Te dejo un link acerca de [Collations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) que podría resolver tu duda.

Comment: Si, en ambas tablas tengo valores con Ñ. Yo tampoco pero esos registros no los pasa.

Comment: Gonzalo, prueba "en lugar del `DELETE`" con un `SELECT`, ¿cuántos registros hay en cada tabla y cuántos resultados obtuviste?. ¿Esas tablas no tienen un Id u otro valor que identifique esos registros? Eliminarlos basados en varchar/strings no creo que sea lo mejor.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ya realice esa prueba, creé una consulta directamente en la base de datos y en vez de un delete hice un select. Efectivamente me trae 12 registros menos de los que debería traer y son los 12 registros que contienen letra "ñ". Por eso deduzco que el problema es que contienen ese caracter.